# How to remove "index.html/" from Laravel Form Builder open()

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I have a form in Laravel 4 that uses:

```
{{ Form::open('login') }}
```

This generates the following:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://[...]/public/index.php/login" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

I have .htaccess et al. configured so that "index.html" is hidden from the URI, so I would like it hidden from these generated URLs, too. Has anyone run into this already and solved it yet?

Comment: See Collin's answer below. Just a note, for your learning purposes: using `.htaccess` to remove the index filename from your URL does not inform Laravel (or PHP for that matter) that this is happening. You need to manually tell Laravel that you are not using it, by removing the `index.php` setting appropriately. PHP/Laravel does not do the guess work for you.

Comment: Thank you. I knew I had to remove it from somewhere, as apache could not remove it from Laravel, but I had no idea where to look. You and Collin have saved me a lot of headache! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit application/config/application.php and remove the index.php. This will effect the form and any URL's generated by route().